# What could block a port on a fresh install of 16.04?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw

I need to share port `18090` on my local are network, however something is blocking it.  `netstat -ltn` shows that `127.0.0.1:18090` is listening.  I have issued both `sudo ufw disable` and `sudo /etc/init.d/ufw stop`, yet for some reason no devices can connect to this port on this server's IP.

What could be blocking this port from listening?

Comment: The process is listening on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @fkraiem it would have to be on the same port though. No other process is listening on `18090` on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: 4 years later, I am also having same problem on ubuntu 20.04, ufw is disabled but still, port is blocked

Answer (score 3):

Whatever process you have listening on 18090 is only listening on your local loopback interface. Incoming connections from other hosts on your LAN are likely hitting some other interface (e.g. the IP address on your eth0 interface), and your daemon/process isn't listening on that interface. Ergo, you will need to tell your process or daemon that is opening port 18090 to either bind to the LAN IP address or to bind to 0.0.0.0 (possibly in it's configuration).

When you can get `netstat -ltn` to list your LAN's IP with port 18090 OR `0.0.0.0:18090`, then you can worry about firewall rules.

Additionally, if you want to 'clear' the firewall rules and be wide open, try `sudo iptables -F`